# Truffle best practices - unit vs integration tests

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-migration, testing

Think about having two contracts:

- MockToken
- Faucet (which takes token address as constructor parameter)

To unit test `Faucet` I would create two new instances:

```
const token = await MockToken.new()
const faucet = await Faucet.new(token.address)
```

Now I can perform all my tests in isolation to be sure that `Faucet` works as expected but how do I make sure that the deployed `Faucet` refers to the correct token address and that I have not mistakenly provided a wrong address in the migration?

Do I just get the `Faucet.deployed()` and check that his token address is the one that I expect? If so, should I do it inside the same file that contains unit tests or in a sepate file?

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better way to do this, but usually, I pre-calculate the expected deployed contract address(es) and then I run a check to validate that the deployed contract address(es) matches the expected address(es), if any don't match, I abort the migration:

```js
const ethers = require('ethers');
const utils = require('../lib/utils/utils.js');
const Governance = artifacts.require("Governance");

const privateKey = process.env["PRIVATE_KEY"];

module.exports = function(deployer, network, accounts) {
  deployer.then(async () => {

    let provider = ethers.getDefaultProvider("rinkeby");
    let walletWithProvider = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey, provider);
    let walletPublicKey = walletWithProvider.address;

    const nonce = await walletWithProvider.getTransactionCount();

    console.log('\r\nCurrent nonce: ', nonce);

    const GovernanceAddress = await utils.getAddress(walletPublicKey, nonce + 1);

    console.log(`\r\nExpected GovernanceAddress: ${GovernanceAddress}`);

    const GovernanceContract = await deployer.deploy(Governance);

    if(GovernanceContract.address.toLowerCase() !== GovernanceAddress) {
        throw new Error("GovernanceContract Address Does Not Match Expected Address (GovernanceAddress) - Aborting Deployment");
    }

  });
}
```

Here is the utils function being used as `utils.getAddress` to pre-calculate the contract address(es):

```js
import { solidityKeccak256 } from 'ethers/utils';
import * as rlp from 'rlp';

export const getAddress = (deployer, nonce) => {
  return (
    '0x' +
    solidityKeccak256(['bytes'], [rlp.encode([deployer, nonce])])
      .slice(12)
      .substring(14)
  );
};
```

Hope that helps in your context :)

Answer (score 0):

When you want two contracts to be closely related I create both before running the tests

```
contract('MyContract', async () => {
    let token
    let faucet

    // This function will execute once before all the tests
    before(async () => {
        token = await MockToken.new()
        faucet = await Faucet.new(token.address)
    })

    it('Faucet', async () => {
        assert(....)
    })
})
```